# Fetch a cell's data from all rows in a table using

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to fetch a cell's data from all rows in a MySQL table and then store the data in an array.

**MySQL Table Name = classes**

```
Column      Type                         Comment  
id          int(11)Auto Increment    
name        varchar(75) []    
teacher     varchar(75) []   
cost        decimal(7,0) [0]
```

I want to create an array using the `name` value in the table from all the rows (13 total) in the table `classes`.

I believe I need something like this, but it isn't working.

```
$names = $db->fetchRows("select `name` from `classes`);
```

I'm not sure if I should use fetchRow or fetchRows and I'm not sure if I need something after `classes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your `$db` class defined somewhere, try this:

```
$names = $db->fetchAll("select `name` from `classes`");
```

If not, you need to read [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).